Auto-applying symbology changes in ArcGIS Pro without clicking Apply every time
I previously tried using a newer version 3.3, It was great to provide a small button (auto-apply) that enables you to make the symbols change automatically immediately after changing the symbol without having to press Apply every time.
Is there a way to do this on Version 3.0 because I did not find this?

If you do not see the auto apply in version 3.0 then it was new functionality introduced at 3.1 or higher. It is highly unlikely that ESRI will retrospectively add functionality that is in newer versions of their software. So the answer is no.

Thank you for the answer. I have returned to using version 3.3 because despite the simplicity of the tool, it is really useful
